# Fold and reduce show non-deterministic behavior when ran in parallel, why?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

so I'm trying to count occurrences of items using Akka Streams.
Underneath example is a simplified version of what I have. I need two pipelines to work concurrently. For some reason, the printed results aren't correct.

Does anyone know why this happens? Am I missing something important regarding substreams?

```scala
/**
 * SIMPLE EXAMPLE
 */
object TestingObject {
  import akka.actor.ActorSystem
  import akka.stream._
  import akka.stream.scaladsl._
  import java.nio.file.Paths
  import akka.util.ByteString
  import counting._
  import graph_components._

  // implicit actor system
  implicit val system:ActorSystem = ActorSystem("Sys")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val customFlow = Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() {
      implicit builder =>
        import GraphDSL.Implicits._


        // Components
        val A   = builder.add(Balance[(Int, Int)](2, waitForAllDownstreams = true));
        val B1   = builder.add(mergeCountFold.async);
        val B2   = builder.add(mergeCountFold.async);
        val C   = builder.add(Merge[(Int, Int)](2));
        val D   = builder.add(mergeCountReduce);

        // Graph
        A ~> B1 ~> C ~> D
        A ~> B2 ~> C

        FlowShape(A.in, D.out);
    })

    // Run
    Source(0 to 101)
      .groupBy(10, x => x % 4)
      .map(x => (x % 4, 1))
      .via(customFlow)
      .mergeSubstreams
      .to(Sink.foreach(println)).run();
  }

  def mergeCountReduce = Flow[(Int, Int)].reduce((l, r) => {
    println("REDUCING");
    (l._1, l._2 + r._2)
  })
  def mergeCountFold = Flow[(Int, Int)].fold[(Int,Int)](0,0)((l, r) => {
    println("FOLDING");
    (r._1, l._2 + r._2)
  })

}
```

Comment: Which usages of `mergeCountReduce` are you replacing with `mergeCountFold`

Comment: Also what exactly do you mean by "only some of the resulting items are outputted" and "miss the first value of the tuple"?  Note that in your example, the difference between `fold` and `reduce` is that `fold` will emit `_1` of the last value seen and `reduce` will emit `_1` of the first value seen.  Since these are both ordering dependent, it's also noteworthy that `Balance` and `Merge` combine (especially with `async` in between) to provide no real ordering guarantees.

Comment: I'm replacing both the usages, I'm or using mergeCountReduce or mergeCountFold, no mixture.

Comment: With "only some values" I mean that the sink that is supposed to print the merged results doesn't print all the results when using Reduce. When using Fold it does print all the results but some of them have 0 as ._1

Comment: ordering doesn't really matter since I'm merging everything afterwards with mergcountReduce/Fold

Comment: The ordering matters in the `reduce`/`fold`...

Comment: I don't understand. How does the order matter?

Comment: Your `reduce` will pass the first `._1` it sees through to the end; your `fold` will pass the last `._1` it sees.

Comment: I know, but since they work on a substream the ._1 will always be the same so it doesn't really matter. The problem I'm stuck with is why reduce and fold act up when ran asynchronously.

Comment: `(0 to 4).map(_ -> 1).reduce((l, r) => l._1 -> (l._2 + r._2))` is `(0, 5)` and `(0 to 4).map(_ -> 1).foldLeft(0 -> 0)((l, r) => r._1 -> (l._2 + r._2))` is `(4, 5)`

Comment: Why would they be the same?

Comment: Those are different indeed, but look at the code please. The source that starts everything is grouped and then the groups are each individually passed through the customFlow. Once inside the customFlow a balance splits the group's items in two and passes each half through the transform Flow. That flow transforms them all into tuples (value, 1). The 'value' is the ._1 and thus will always be the same inside that instance of the customFlow. Afterwards each half is folded/reduced and later merged into a single stream and then merged/reduced again.

Comment: This happens for each group and thus the ._1 is always the same.

Comment: `groupBy` doesn't do what you seem to think it does

Comment: Believe me If I tell you that I want that to be it. Care to explain? I thought groupBy splits my main stream into multiple substreams, one for each group. Those substreams then each of them go through what is after the groupBy?

Comment: Look at the signature for `groupBy[K]`.  Note that `K` is the result of the grouping function (`Out => K`) but nowhere appears in the `SubFlow` which is the result of `groupBy`.  Thus, `groupBy` passes through the individual elements, not the grouping key, so the "values" aren't the same in the custom flow (0, 4, 8, ... 100 get sent through subflow 0)

Comment: My apologies, my mind got mixed up with another example I worked out. I have edited the example. Now, after the groupBy, each substream of single elements is transformed into a stream of (key, element). My question remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two observations:

- `mergeCountReduce` will emit the first key it saw with the sum of the values seen (and will fail the stream if it didn't see any elements)
- `mergeCountFold` will emit the last key it saw and the sum of the values seen (and will emit a key and value of zero if it didn't see any elements)

(in both cases, though the key is always the same)

Neither of those observations are affected by the `async` boundary.

In the context of the preceding `Balance` operator, though, `async` introduces an implicit buffer, which prevents the graph it wraps from backpressuring until that buffer is full.  `Balance` sends stream values to the first output which isn't backpressuring, so if the stage after `Balance` is not dramatically slower than the upstream, `Balance` may send values only to one output (`B1` in this case).

In that scenario, with `reduce`, `B1` would emit the key and count, while `B2` fails, causing the whole stream to fail.

For `fold`, in that scenario, `B1` would emit the key and count, while `B2`, not having seen any values would emit `(0,0)`.  The merge would emit them in the order they emitted (reasonable to assume a 50/50 chance), so the final fold would then either have the key and the count or zero and the count.

Comment: So async is the troublemaker? If I drop this though there's no advantage in splitting the stream in two. Any solution to this?

Comment: Also, I don't know if you've ran the code but when the reduce version is used nothing is printed at all. Any idea of why this happens?

Comment: Actually, I'd forgotten what happens when `reduce` has no elements, editing...

Comment: The fold version fails as well I think. Nothing is printed.

Comment: Set aside what happens when one of them doesn't have any elements, how do I make sure both of them get a balanced amount of elements?

Comment: You might try making only `B2` async, as that would probably allow some elements to go down that path.

Comment: Removing `.async` from `B1` and `B2` should still allow the two sides of that custom flow to work in parallel (this might be another case of `async` being poorly named, e.g. `map(...).async` has almost no relationship to `mapAsync(N)(Future { ... })`)

Comment: `.async` pipelines a stream (allowing elements to be in flight on either side with a slight backpressure break), `mapAsync` and the fan-out graph topologies can introduce parallelism.

Comment: Wait so the balance alone introduces parallelism?

Comment: After some experimentation, `Balance` alone does not lead to parallelism, but if `Balance` waits for all outlets to materialize before routing, it does send records to both: `Balance[(Int, Int)](2, waitForAllDownstreams = true)`